# Insert value into Azure DevOps Custom Fields through Rest Api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've added some custom fields for Test Plan in Azure DevOps. But when I try to create a new Test Plan through the Rest API call, it is only creating a Test Plan with default fields populated, while custom fields remain blank.

I've tried using both the field name (like *Team Name*) along with field reference name (like `custom.TeamName`) but to no avail. Even `Get` is also not exposing custom fields. Is some extra configuration required for custom fields, or it is a code related issue?

**Details:** I've created one Inherited process under the organization, and then under Process->Test Plan I've created new fields in the Test Plan, as shown in the screen shot:

[image: Snapshot of one such custom field]

I've tried below code to create Test Plan as Work Item and successfully created it with extra fields. But as I couldn't create a test suite independently, it is not behaving properly.

I've created a `JsonPatchDocument` and added all the fields (adding just one here) like below code:

```
JsonPatchDocument patchDocument= new JsonPatchDocument();

patchDocument.Add(
{
Operation=Operation.Add,
Path="/fields/System.TeamName",
Value="Xander"
}
);

VssConnection connection=new VssConnection(uri,credential);
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient= connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHTTPClient>();
WorkItem res=workItemTrackingHTTPClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument,project,"Test Plan").Result;
```

It is creating the Test Plan, but not Test Suite. So it is acting weirdly. Kindly check this.

Comment: @DanielMann I'm able to create new test plan using Rest Api.The problem is Rest Api is not exposing these custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

> Insert value into Azure DevOps Custom Fields through Rest Api

I could reproduce this issue with the REST API [Test Plans - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-plans/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

I think this should be related to the REST API, that because even if I use the REST API [Test Plans - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-plans/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get the custom field, but the request body does not include the custom field.

Since we could not get the custom field, we could not use the POST or PATCH for the custom filed.

You could add this request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]